# NTP is not working in ubuntu

Tags: ntp

I installed NTP on my server and client then I changed time in client. When I run the `ntpd -dq` command, it shows:

```
Unable to bind to wild card address 0.0.0.0 , maybe another process is running
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your client time with ntp-client , i suggest you to run this command :

Example:

ntpdate ntp.myserver.net

Or

ntpdate 202.16.232.1

you can change word "ntp.myserver.net" and "202.16.232.1" your domain and your ip_server .